# First Ruby on Rails App: use v3 (Beta) or 2.3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Now that Rails 3.0 beta has been released, should I spend time building my first Rails application on 2.3 or does it make more sense to use the beta?

Comment: If you decide to go with 2.3, I'd still recommend keeping an eye on version 3 just so you know what's coming when it's finally released.

Comment: They all summed it up pretty well. As of now... Work in 2.3 and Play in 3.0.

Comment: Use something stable (2.3).  I tried to stay on the bleeding edge with my first Rails app.  Dealing with deprecation became a maintenance nightmare.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd suggest sticking with the non-beta version (2.3). Chances are tutorials and/or webcasts you might use are for the older version. Go for version 3 only if it includes features you actually need that are not in 2.3.

Answer (score 3):

If you plan on actually building something with Rails, go with version 2.3 because it's, well, not a beta (stable), and because most tutorials are geared towards the 2.x series.

If you're just going to mess with it, I say go with version 3 for two reasons: you'll be better prepared when it does come out, and you get to play with the new features. But if you're not going to do anything serious with it, it doesn't really matter which you pick, so it's your call.

Answer (score 3):

I disagree with other answers. Rails 3 does a number of things differently than 2.3. You should learn right away the new way to code. It's not harder and you won't have time to re-learn in a few short weeks.

Rails 3 beta is stable enough. You will run into few problems.

Answer (score 1):

Your learning. Use something that is stable. Rail 2.3.x is stable and 3.0 is not.

Comment: To clarify what I meant by stable, I mean you might need to get your hands dirty digging around in gem code or run in to problems that are not well documented. Of course that is getting better fast.

Answer (score 1):

If you are strapped on a deadline for your app, use Rails 2.3.

But I encourage you to use Rails 3.0 as it'll teach you a lot about the framework works when you do encounter problems.